# HTML: Div is not in align?

Tags: css

Hello i used Bootstrap and my 2 div col-md-6 and col-md-6 are not in align in height.
[image: in img you can see both are not in align]

Comment: Please show the code you currently have and what you have tried so that others can help you.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use this css for the first div.

```
div.col-md-6 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: @SatyamDhameliya Please accept the answer by ticking it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to align vertical align here is to add padding from top in the first div.Your second div have buttons and must be having padding also.

Comment: You are welcome.please upvote or mark my answer if this helped.thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use min-height for both using class to div. It will solve your query.
eg:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 mycol">
</div>
 <div class="col-md-6 mycol">
</div>
```

style.css

```
.mycol{
min-height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the code, it's hard to find the cause, but I guess your two div are without a css height property and then adapt to their content.

The div on the right contains items that seems to have a padding on top and bottom, resulting in an item with a greatest height than the one on the left.

Your two div are aligned on the top and as it's already been mentionned you need to add the same padding on the left and right cols (I don't like the vertical align answer, as it work in this case, but could cause issues as the cols height could change).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have a scenario where you text will wrap to the next line, you can use `line-height` which will be same for both the sections.